# Ways to "click" or tap on mobile devices using Browserstack and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browserstack

I have a test code that works with Browserstack and basically plays a video on a page.

```
playBackButton = _webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label='Start Playback']"))
try{
        playBackButton.click();
}
```

Which works fine except on mobile devices it logs a click in the log, but the video doesn't start. No exception, just doesn't play.

Can someone show a working example of sending taps to mobile devices *running in Browserstack*?

Comment: Are you sure the xpath locator is the same for the mobile version?

Comment: yes, we hooked up a real device and located the same button with the same `xpath`.

Comment: Use JavaScript executor this to perform click event

Comment: @AnkurSingh I tried, but it produced inconsistent results. The thing is we need the code to be working with multiple players. In VideoJS, for instance, the click event dispatched with JavaScript works fine. But with JW player there's no button really and we click a div. Which, again, works fine with Selenium's `webdriver.click()` in browsers, but not with mobile devices

Comment: You can use try catch to handle mobile version click event .. it will work as if else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running tests on ios devices, please ensure you are using the capability:

```
 caps.setCapability("nativeWebTap",true);
```

and the driver should be an instance of IOSDriver

```
IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Similarly, for Android, ensure you are using AndroidDriver

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Working sample for iOS with xpath:

```
 caps.setCapability("nativeWebTap",true);
 IOSDriver driver = null;
 try {
     driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
 WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='-details'])[1]"));
 ele.click();
 driver.quit();
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to set up different webdrivers when running the tests in Browserstack?

Comment: Yes. You only need to replace the 127.0.0.1 url with BrowserStack’s hub url. And include a BrowserStack specific capability called ‘realMobile’: true

Comment: No problems with marking your answer as accepted to recognize your efforts! However, it doesn't fully address my issue. Firstly, because it relies on Appium entities, whereas I'm just using Selenium. Secondly, the issue doesn't seem to be related to clicking in general, but more specifically to the video playback. Currently I was able to figure out that even executing a JS that specifically calls `play()` method of JW or VidoeJS player, doesn't work...